# How to run docker images in containerd using ctr in CLI?

Tags: docker, containers, containerd

Am exploring on how to use `containerd` in place of dockerd. This is for learning only and as a cli tool rather than with any pipelines or automation.

So far, documentation in regards to using containerd in cli (via `ctr`) is very limited. Even the official docs are using Go lang to utilize `containerd` directly.

What I have learnt is `ctr` command plays the role of `docker` command to control `containerd`. I have thus far created a docker image and exported it to .tar format. Now using `ctr i import hello.tar` I have imported it as an image.

Now `ctr i ls` gives me the following output:

```
REF                                     TYPE                                       DIGEST                                                                  SIZE      PLATFORMS   LABELS
docker.io/library/hello-java-app:latest application/vnd.oci.image.manifest.v1+json sha256:ef4acfd85c856ea020328959ff3cac23f37fa639b7edfb1691619d9bfe1e06c7 628.7 MiB linux/amd64 -
```

Trying to run a container asks me for the image id:

```
root@slave-node:~/images/sample# ctr run
ctr: image ref must be provided
root@slave-node:~/images/sample# ctr run docker.io/library/hello-java-app:latest
ctr: container id must be provided
```

I am not sure on where to get the image id from. Are there any docs related to `ctr` or `containerd` that could be helpful for a beginner?

**Just running the image as a container would be sufficient for me.**

Comment: Some things to consider when using more arguments with `ctr run`. E.g. use both, `--uidmap` and `--gidmap` in case you want to run your container without having root privileges on the host (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66478456/run-container-with-containerds-ctr-by-means-of-uidmap-to-map-to-non-root-user-o) why). Also using `--net-host` to make the host network available does not work with rootless containers (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66547508/how-to-properly-run-a-container-with-containerds-ctr-using-uidmap-gidmap-and/66567309#66567309))

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The `ctr run` command creates a container and executes it

```
ctr run <imageName> <uniqueValue>
```

> e.g., ctr run --rm docker.io/library/hello-java-app:latest mypod

This executes my basic docker java image with a print statement:

```
~~~~
HelloWorld from Java Application running in Docker.
~~~~
```

**Steps followed:**

#### 1 - A java file:

```java
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("~~~~\nHelloWorld from Java Application running in Docker.\n~~~~");
    }
}
```

#### 2 - An image:

```
FROM java:8
COPY HelloWorld.java .
RUN javac HelloWorld.java
CMD ["java", "HelloWorld"]
```

#### 3 - Build image and export as .tar

- `docker build -t hello-java-app .`
- `docker save -o ~/images/sample/hello-java-app.tar hello-java-app`

#### 4 - Import image (.tar) into containerd:

- `ctr i import hello-java-app.tar`

```bash
unpacking docker.io/library/hello-java-app:latest (sha256:ef4acfd85c856ea020328959ff3cac23f37fa639b7edfb1691619d9bfe1e06c7)...done
```

- `ctr i ls`

```bash
REF                                     TYPE                                       DIGEST                                                                  SIZE      PLATFORMS   LABELS
docker.io/library/hello-java-app:latest application/vnd.oci.image.manifest.v1+json sha256:ef4acfd85c856ea020328959ff3cac23f37fa639b7edfb1691619d9bfe1e06c7 628.7 MiB linux/amd64 -
```

#### 5 - Run the image:

- `ctr run --rm docker.io/library/hello-java-app:latest mypod`

```bash
~~~~
HelloWorld from Java Application running in Docker.
~~~~
```

---

> I am still unsure of the use of creating a container. The run command creates a container and executes it once. `ctr c create` just creates a container which can then be listed with `ctr c ls` but I am not able to utilize them in any meaningful way. Can anyone clarify its purpose?

---

PS:
Without the --rm flag, a new unique value is needed to be entered for every `run` as the old container is retained and we get an error: `ctr: snapshot "mypod": already exists`

Comment: How can you use classical docker options in the "ctr run" command, like forwarding ports (-p) or detaching the container(-d) or binding volumes (-v)

Comment: @RedaDrissi as of version 1.3.3 detaching with `-d` and binding volumes with `--mount`. Not sure about the port forwarding though. More details with `man ctr`.

Comment: Step 5 `--rm` is in the wrong position. As shown it is treated as an exec arg. I initially ran the recommended command, which errored. Cleanup required `snapshot remove` and `container delete` for `v1`. The command works fine when `--rm` is in the right place (before the image name).

Comment: @RedaDrissi if you'd really like to use `docker` CLI syntax when interacting with containerd directly, you might want to given [`nerdctl`](https://github.com/containerd/nerdctl) a shot.
Note that, because containerd's API is considerably lower level than that of Docker server, `nerdctl` is quite the [thick client](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_client), and is not officially supported for any purpose outside of debugging containerd in a familial and user convenient way.