# How can I share my docker images with containerd runtime?

Tags: docker, containerd

I used to work with docker images and now I am trying to run containers using containerd runtime. So, I want to share my prebuilt docker images with ctr, Is that possible ?
How can I do that please ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run docker images in containerd using ctr in CLI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59393496/how-to-run-docker-images-in-containerd-using-ctr-in-cli)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, both implement the OCI Image Spec. If your image is accessible to your containerd installation, it should work seamless.

One example of running the redis:alpine image from Docker Hub:

```
ctr image pull docker.io/library/redis:alpine
ctr run docker.io/library/redis:alpine myid
```

Comment: I want to use my local images that I've already pulled with docker or I build it locally , is there a way to do that ?

Comment: You can save the image from `docker` using `docker save [your image] > image.tar` and then import it into `ctr` using `ctr image import image.tar`.

Comment: okay, that solved the inexsitant issue of mine,  thank you !