# run container with containerd's ctr by means of uidmap to map to non-root user on the host

Tags: docker, namespaces, containerd

To better understand how to use the `--uidmap` with `ctr`, I've created a test container by means of the following steps. The `containerd` version is `1.4.3`.

## Build and Run Container:

1. Build Dockerfile

   ```
   $ cat Dockerfile
   FROM alpine
   ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh"]
   ```

   with

   ```
   $ docker build -t test .
   Sending build context to Docker daemon  143.1MB
   Step 1/2 : FROM alpine                         
    ---> d6e46aa2470d                             
   Step 2/2 : ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh"]              
    ---> Running in 560b09f9b287                  
   Removing intermediate container 560b09f9b287   
    ---> 8506bfeab109                             
   Successfully built 8506bfeab109                
   Successfully tagged test:latest
   ```
2. Save the image as tar ball

   ```
   $ docker save test > test.tar
   ```
3. Import it with containerd's `ctr`

   ```
   $ sudo ctr i import test.tar
   unpacking docker.io/library/test:latest (sha256:9f7dabf0e4feadbca9bdc180422a3f2cdd7b545445180a3c23de8129dc95f29b)...done
   ```
4. Create and run the container

   ```
   $ sudo ctr run --uidmap 0:5000:4999 docker.io/library/test:latest test
   ```

   The uid map should map the container internal uid of 0 (root) to 5000 corresponding to ctr's manpage:

   > --uidmap="": run inside a user namespace with the specified UID mapping range; specified with the format container-uid:host-uid:length

## Check UID in container and on host:

Within the container:

```
ps -eo ruser,rgroup,comm 
RUSER    RGROUP   COMMAND
root     root     sh     
root     root     ps
```

On the host:

```
$ ps -eo uid,gid,cmd | grep /bin/sh
  126   128 /bin/sh /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-greeter-session /usr/sbin/unity-greeter
    0     0 /bin/sh
```

## Issue

It seems to not work, `/bin/sh` runs as root (uid=0) within the container as well as on the host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was searching for a while until I checked containerd's code and found this within `cmd/ctr/commands/run/run_unix.go`:

```
149       if uidmap, gidmap := context.String("uidmap"), context.String("gidmap"); uidmap != "" && gidmap != "" {
150         uidMap, err := parseIDMapping(uidmap)
151         if err != nil {
152           return nil, err
153         }
154         gidMap, err := parseIDMapping(gidmap)
155         if err != nil {
156           return nil, err
157         }
```

which basically means:
You have to provide both, the `uidmap` **AND** the `gidmap`, otherwise it won't work.

Running the above container again with

```
$ sudo ctr run --uidmap 0:5000:4999 --gidmap 0:5000:4999 docker.io/library/test:latest test
```

did the trick.

Within the container:

```
ps -eo ruser,rgroup,comm  
RUSER    RGROUP   COMMAND 
root     root     sh      
root     root     ps
```

On the host:

```
$ ps -eo uid,gid,cmd | grep /bin/sh
  126   128 /bin/sh /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-greeter-session /usr/sbin/unity-greeter
 5000  5000 /bin/sh
```