# How to properly run a container with containerd's ctr using --uidmap/gidmap and --net-host option

Tags: containers, linux-namespaces, containerd, runc

I'm running a container with `ctr` and next to using user namespaces to map the user within the container (root) to another user on the host, I want to make the host networking available for the container. For this, I'm using the `--net-host` option. Based on a very simple test container

```
$ cat Dockerfile
FROM alpine
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh"]
```

I try it with

```
sudo ctr run -rm --uidmap "0:1000:999" --gidmap "0:1000:999" --net-host docker.io/library/test:latest test
```

which gives me the following error

```
ctr: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:449: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\\"sysfs\\\" to rootfs \\\"/run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/default/test/rootfs\\\" at \\\"/sys\\\" caused \\\"operation not permitted\\\"\"": unknown
```

Everything works fine if I either

1. remove the `--net-host` flag or
2. remove the `--uidmap`/`--gidmap` arguments

I tried to add the user with the host `uid=1000` to the `netdev` group, but still the same error.
Do I maybe need to use networking namespaces?

**EDIT:**

Meanwhile found out that it's an issue within `runc`. In case I use user namespaces by adding the following to the `config.json`

```
    "linux": {
        "uidMappings": [
            {
                "containerID": 0,
                "hostID": 1000,
                "size": 999
            }
        ],
        "gidMappings": [
            {
                "containerID": 0,
                "hostID": 1000,
                "size": 999
            }
        ],
```

and additionally do **not** use a network namespace, which means **leaving out** the entry

```
            {
                "type": "network"
            },
```

within the `"namespaces"` section, I got the following error from `runc`:

```
$ sudo runc run test
WARN[0000] exit status 1
ERRO[0000] container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:449: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\\"sysfs\\\" to rootfs \\\"/vagrant/test/rootfs\\\" at \\\"/sys\\\" caused \\\"operation not permitted\\\"\""
container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:449: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\\"sysfs\\\" to rootfs \\\"/vagrant/test/rootfs\\\" at \\\"/sys\\\" caused \\\"operation not permitted\\\"\""
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer from [this issue in `runc`](https://github.com/opencontainers/runc/issues/799). It's basically a restriction within the kernel that a user that does not own the network namespace does not have the `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` capability and without that can't mount `sysfs`. Since the user on the host that the root user within the container is mapped to did not create the host network namespace, it does not have `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` there.

From the discussion in [the `runc` issue](https://github.com/opencontainers/runc/issues/799), I do see the following options for now:

1. remove mounting of `sysfs`.

   Within the `config.json` that `runc` uses, remove the following section within `"mounts"`:

   ```
           {
           "destination": "/sys",
           "type": "sysfs",
           "source": "sysfs",
           "options": [
               "nosuid",
               "noexec",
               "nodev",
               "ro"
           ]
       },
   ```

   In my case, I also couldn't mount `/etc/resolv.conf`. By removing these 2, the container did run fine and had host network access. This does not work with `ctr` though.
2. setup a bridge from the host network namespace to the network space of the container ([see here](https://github.com/opencontainers/runc/issues/799#issuecomment-216639832) and [slirp4netns](https://github.com/rootless-containers/slirp4netns)).
3. use docker or podman if possible that seem to use [slirp4netns](https://github.com/rootless-containers/slirp4netns) for this purpose. There is [an old moby issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/21800) that also might be interesting.